# Can't make new profiles, or edit settings

Tags: profile

When I try to create a new civicrm profile, or to edit the setting of an existing one, there is just a blank space with no buttons or fields. See the attached screenshots.[image]  I'm using civicrm 4.6.10 and Drupal 7.41

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of my groups' other tech people figured out that it was the file permissions in the CiviCRM template_c and ConfigAndLog directories.  Weird.

Answer (score 0):

I have tested the same against CiviCRM Version 4.6.10 and it works perfectly. So please try to reinstall CiviCRM or try to install an fresh copy of CiviCRM and do the testing - Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things you can try, most of which are detailed here: [Troubleshooting JavaScript in CiviCRM](http://forum.civicrm.org/index.php/topic,35850).  Please update your questions with what you've tried if you still need help!

Also, please edit your question to specify your CMS.  Try switching your CMS's theme to Bartik (for Drupal) or twentyfifteen (for Wordpress).  Does this change the behavior?

Finally - please check your CiviCRM logs and PHP logs.  If you post your CMS version and web server software, someone can help you find them.

UPDATE: Now we're getting somewhere!  $.browser is a major clue.  CiviCRM doesn't use $.browser (it's deprecated, and removed as of jQuery 1.9).  So my guess is another module.  Are you running the "jQuery Update" Drupal module?  If so, set it to a version < 1.9 and see if it fixes the problem.  You might also want to find the module that's calling this outdated jQuery construct and see if you actually need it.  You can search your codebase for "$.browser", or just shut off all your non-core extensions and turn half of them on at a time until you've figured out which one causes the error.

Comment: Just edited my post to include the CMS - Drupal 7.41  and I know it's on apache, not sure which version off the top of my head though.

Comment: Apache 2.2.22 on debian

Comment: Tried Bartik, no luck.

Comment: Also tried looking at any jquery errors that might pop up, saw "Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated. Use defaultPrevented instead." and "TypeError: $.browser is undefined"

Comment: @MattMuchowski I updated my answer to reflect your new info.

Comment: Any suggestions on how to search my codebase?

Comment: I set the jquery version to 1.7 and still get the error.

Comment: @MattMuchowski if you have command-line access, use grep (in OS X/Linux) or find (in Windows).  If you're not comfortable with the command line, just turn off all the non-core modules to see if it goes away, then turn them back on a few at a time.

Comment: Yea, I did grep -rnw "$.browser" and it seemed to point to jquery_update, calendar/theme, and tableofcontents, I disabled jquery_update and tableofcontents, the calendar was greyed out.  Still no luck.

Comment: Looking at the source code, I saw this little nugget, "        <!-- .tpl file invoked: CRM/UF/Form/Group.tpl. Call via form.tpl if we have a form in the page. -->           <form  action="/civicrm/admin/uf/group/add" method="post" name="Group" id="Group" class="CRM_UF_Form_Group" data-warn-changes="true" >" Which seems to be the code that gets called to create and edit profiles.  It seems like it's not being called?

Comment: Could it be something related to acl permissions?

Comment: It does the same thing on the Misc. Settings page /civicrm/admin/setting/misc?reset=1   where there are no fields or buttons.